# Delete folders with a common string but with spaces in folder names

Tags: windows, batch

I have a bunch of folders, some with spaces in their folder names and some not. They all have a certain string common in their folder names and they all lie inside a single directory. For e.g

- new star folder
- mystarfolder
- somestar folder
- starfolder

I want to delete all the above folders in a batch file. I tried the following, but it doesn't work with spaces in folder names

```
FOR /D %%A IN (*star*) DO RD /Q /S %%A
```

How to do it?
May be I could use 8.3 names, but how to use it in the above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...Put quotes around the name: `"%%A"`

```
for /d %%a in (*star*) do rd/s/q "%%a"
```